# How to implement difference aggregations / rollups on time series data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series

I have a situation where I will be collect many time series metrics (electricity used, hours used, hours idle) from operating equipment in a manufacturing plan.  I need to create many different rollup numbers on individual and grouped assets.  For example, I need to create min, max, average electricity used over 1,5,10,30 days for a given machine.  Create same types of metrics for different groups of machines.... Many of the calculated values are driven from the raw values retrieved from the assets.

What is the best approach for calculating these values within a Cassandra environment?

1. Do I need to create 'batch jobs' that execute the calculations?
2. It seems as if there are some built in data types (counter) in Cassandra, but seem to be some issues (simply reading some comments on stack overflow)
3. Has anyone integrate Cassandra with a Twitter storm or something  to constantly update the counters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open-source project called Blueflood that does exactly this. You could likely use it directly out of the box to fill your use-case, or fork the repo and modify as necessary.

- Documentation and homepage: http://blueflood.io/
- Source-code: https://github.com/rackerlabs/blueflood
- Irc: #blueflood on Freenode

(Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the project)